# How to make the scroll bar to move to a accurate place

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I have a list with scroll bar. Also there is a button that when pressed, it moves to a certain `#id` and scroll bar also moves to make that element visible. But it is not accurate. It moves, but not always to the exact place. How can I make this scroll function to be accurate:

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/danials/anpXP/1/

My jQuery code:

```
function next() {
    $(".list li").css("background", "grey");
    goToByScroll(myID);
    $("#" + myID).css("background", "red");
    myID = $("#" + myID).next("li").attr("id");
}

function goToByScroll(id) {
    $('.list').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top - $("#" + id).height()
    },
        'slow');
}
```

In the demo try pressing the next button, and you'll see in some items the scroll moves but not correctly.

Any idea?

Comment: The problem is that in every other `GoToByScroll`, `offset().top` increases by 1 instead of the proper amount, not sure why, but you can start there.

Comment: [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpXP/2/) will work. The problem is that as the screen scrolls, the offset of the element changes, as it gets closer to the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are getting the `offset` of each element as you scroll down the list.

[Offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) is:

```
The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element
relative to the document.
```

So this makes the `offset` of the box smaller, the further down the list you go.

What you need to do is figure out what the height+margin of an element is and do some math:

```
var myID = $(".list").children().first().attr("id");

function next() {
    var li = $("#"+myID);
    $(".list li").css("background", "grey");
    var offset = parseInt(li.height())+parseInt(li.css("margin-top"));
    $('.list').animate({scrollTop: offset*(myID-1)},'slow');
    $("#"+myID).css("background", "red");
    myID++;
}
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpXP/4/) shows it in action. What it does is get the height+margin of the current element, and then multiplies it by how many elements down the list you are.

This only works assuming that all elements are the same size and that they have incremental IDs though.

**UPDATE**

If you want to make it work with Dynamic IDs, all you do is set an incremental variable to keep track of how many you have iterated through, and then grab the next ID similarly to how you did before:

```
var myID = $(".list").children().first().attr("id");
var inc = 1;

function next() {
    var li = $("#"+myID);
    $(".list li").css("background", "grey");
    var offset = parseInt(li.height())+parseInt(li.css("margin-top"));
    $('.list').animate({scrollTop: offset*(inc-1)},'slow');
    $("#"+myID).css("background", "red");
    myID = $("#"+myID).next().attr("id");
    inc++;
}
```

And here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpXP/11/).

Comment: I tried to make a different version that works with different IDs (not incremental ones). It does not work yet. Can you have a look at it please? [http://jsfiddle.net/danials/anpXP/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/danials/anpXP/8/)

Comment: @DanielJJ Sorry it took so long for me to respond. I've updated my answer with a dynamic ID version.